# Running Selenium webdriver scripts on selenium Grid

Tags: xml, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

```
           I am new to testing,now i am working on selenium Grid.
```

1. I am running my TestNG suite on different browsers and platforms.The framework used is java, TestNG,webdriver,eclipse.
2. Test runs fine while running suite in chrome and firefox on LINUX .I set the environment LINUX system as hub and LINUX systems as nodes.
3. Using Selenium Grid when I make the LINUX system the "Hub" and my other Windows machine a "node" The connection is not established/connection timed out and does not match with platform LINUX.

   How to connect windows System as either node or hub to LINUX system.

Comment: Are you able to ping the windows machn from linux system and vice-versa? Are both on same sub-net?

Comment: yes both are in same sub-net.

Comment: on windows machn what is th selenium node command you are passing?

Comment: i tried in different ways

Comment: i tried in different ways like java  -Dwebdriver.ie.driver="path of ie driver.exe" selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar -role node -hub http://"path of hub" -browser browserName=ie,platform=WINDOWS -port

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://deors.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/selenium-webdriver-grid-1/)...